# HTTP Status Code 200-299 or 400

Tags: google-app-engine

I am adding my tasks to the Task Queue. But when the tasks run, I get the following error:

> "Process terminated because it failed to respond to the start request with an HTTP status code of 200-299 or 404."

**Java Code:**

```
String url = "/myapp/showDetails.htm?userEmail="+userEmail;
                Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
                TaskOptions objTskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl(url)
                                            .header("Host",BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService()
                                            .getBackendAddress("BackendName")).method(Method.GET)
                                            .retryOptions(RetryOptions.Builder.withTaskRetryLimit(5).maxDoublings(3));
                queue.add(objTskOptions);
                logger.info("Task Queue URL::"+objTskOptions.getUrl());
```

Why am I getting this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Task Queue runs code asynchronously and it's result is not visible to the user. It seems that your url `/myapp/showDetails.htm` is producing html?

Also make sure that you can actually invoke the full url by hand (executing on your backend instance): e.g. `shareduserlevelcontacts.yourapp.appspot.com/myapp/showDetails.htm?userEmail=some@email`

Comment: still i am facing same issue. after some time backend stops automatically. can i anyone tell me what is issue with it.?

Comment: First time, when i hit that backend url, It shows hard-dead-line error. any solution for that? I am using spring-annotations.